# neo4j Model Creation from flat CSV

Tags: csv, neo4j, graph-databases

I am doing a proof of concept and need a little guidance. I have a flat file that contains the following attributes: ID, Name, Email, Gender, StreetAddress, City, State, Zip, Phone, AltPhone, SSN (all fake data.)

I want to import this in a way that each Person is a node, each address is a node, each ssn is a node, and each phone/altphone is a node. This is to mimic many of the examples of fraud ring detection. How can I load this CSV file, creating these relationships? There will be duplicate addresses and phone numbers but where duplicates exist, only 1 node should exist.

Is there a way to do this using the standard LOAD CSV or do I need to break all this data up, relationally, outside of neoj4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the [`MERGE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html) Cypher command. `MERGE` will look for a pattern and create it if it doesn't exist, but will not create duplicate data.

First, define uniqueness constraints based on your data model. You should define a uniqueness constraint for any Label property used in a MERGE statement:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.personID IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (phone:Phone) ASSERT phone.number IS UNIQUE;
...
```

Then, using `MERGE` with `LOAD CSV` will look something like this (depending on the data model you want):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///flat_file.csv" AS row
MERGE (p:Person {personID: row.ID})
SET p.name = row.Name,
    p.email = row.Email,
    p.gender = row.Gender
MERGE (phone:PhoneNumber {number: row.Phone})
MERGE (altPhone:PhoneNumber {number: row.AltPhone})
MERGE (ssn:SSN {number: row.SSN})
MERGE (address:StreetAddress {address: row.StreetAddress})
MERGE (city:City {name: row.City})
MERGE (state:State {name: row.State})
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_SSN]->(ssn)
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_PHONE]->(phone)
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_ALT_PHONE]->(altPhone)
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_ADDRESS]->(address)
MERGE (address)-[:IS_IN]->(city)
MERGE (city)-[:IS_IN]->(state)
```

Comment: Followed this to the (near) T and it worked flawlessly. Thank you so much. now I need to look into querying the data in the correct way. I set up several of the entries to share phone numbers and addresses that should create a nice little ring.

Answer (score 2):

The general recommendation is to break up the `cypher` statements in `LOAD CSV` to accomplish what you need in steps.  Simply, you wouldn't do everything in a single `LOAD CSV` statement. You might create the SSN nodes, and then Address nodes, etc.

Moreover, you will want to look at creating Indexes and leverage `MERGE` for rows that may be duplicated.

Here is a [good article](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/) on things to consider when using LOAD CSV.

And a post from Mark on [loading data](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/).  Mark has a ton of great posts, so I would encourage you to poke around his blog.

Lastly, [check out the doc's](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html) for `Merge`.

Comment: Awesome. Will do. I am quite new to graphDB's (like 2 days new) so this is all very interesting.